# Why do we update() before we draw()?

Tags: three.js, glfw, cinder

This never made sense to me. I looked at GLFW's and Three.js' examples and Cinder's implementation which actually has [this comment](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/dev/src/cinder/app/AppImplCocoaBasic.mm#L135) in there:

> mark all windows as ready to draw; this really only matters the first
>   time, to ensure the first update() fires before draw()

All three libraries seem to be doing that and I don't understand why. There really is no point in updating the i.e. position of something that's never been drawn on screen or is there?

Here's what my loop looks like:

1. Draw the (first) frame
2. Swap buffers
3. Update events
4. Animate (with the input from the events), update logic, ...
5. Start from the top

This order makes a lot more sense to me but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it makes perfect sense to update objects first and then draw them.

Imagine you animate a ball going from one side of the screen to the other and back just like a pendulum. Imagine you also want it to actually reflect real time in your computer. If you draw your scene before updating the ball's position, then where your ball will be positioned in the first frame? Unless you set it's initial position manually, it would be at zero point of your scene, which might be completely out of it's intended trajectory. If you decide to initialize it's position before start of animation, it might happen that there is a time gap causing it to be in the wrong position too.

But if you always update it's position before drawing, it will be on the right place right from the first rendered frame.

But to be honest - nobody will probably notice the first frame, so it is more sense of logic doing it that way rather than any practical reason. I just feel it makes more sense to prepare your scene before drawing it, not vice versa.

Comment: Zero-initialization is actually a good point; can't believe I didn't thing of that. I guess conceptually you'd initialize all variables in the setup method but then you'd end up with a lot of duplicated code I guess.

Comment: yes, exactly. When I think about it more, also last frame would be incorrect. If you draw before update, then your frame basically shows objects in state they "were" in the last render cycle. If you want to implement some kind of play/pause functionality, then if you paused your animation, you would not see the last frame, but the one before it. When you'd started it again, then you would first see the frame that was supposed to be the last one before pause.